# Duplicate mount points on Mac

Tags: snow-leopard, mount

I'm having a problem where the name of my Windows drive changes periodically on my Mac with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Example: The Windows drive might be named drive/dept now, but next the name might be drive/dept-2 or drive/dept-4.

I need the location of this drive to be constant to run a script. With the periodic name change I have to check what the name is and adjust the script each time I run it.

Why is this happening? Is there anyway I can stop this?

Comment: I would be keen to know the answers.  If you could post the script you are running, we could come up with a work around where the script checks the name before it runs and adjusts itself accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, this seems like an issue with unmounting the drive not working properly or an unexpected restart of the system. When a drive is unmounted, the mount point under `/Volumes/` should be gone. Otherwise Mac OS X would create a new mount point with suffixes like "-1", "-2" and so on since a name that's currently used cannot be replaced without a proper unmount.

There are a few things you could do to resolve this issue:

1. Ensure that you always eject the drive correctly.
2. Restart the system.
3. [Remove the duplicate mount point in /Volumes](https://support.apple.com/kb/TS2474)
4. Apply the combo updater for [Mac OS X 10.6.8 v1.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1400) and see if that helps.

References:
[Remove the duplicate mount point in /Volumes](https://support.apple.com/kb/TS2474)
[Drives in OS X appearing with '-1' appended to their names](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20061498-263.html)